# Makefile: if file exists and is younger than 5 minutes do X else nothing

Tags: makefile

On Ubuntu 16.10, I'm trying to express the following statement in a makefile:

```
if file exists and is younger than 5 minutes do X else nothing
```

Currently, I have part of the solution, I believe.

```
compile_service:
ifeq ($(wildcard $(FILES)/$(CLASS).java)),"") #If file does not exist then $(wildcard file) will evaluate to an empty string.
else
ifeq ???
    CLASSPATH=$(RT) javac $(FILES)/$(CLASS).java
    $(CMD) $(FILES)/$(CLASS).class
endif
endif
```

However, I have issues with checking the age and also not sure if this is a good way to do it.

The purpose is that I don't recompile a Java file if it hasn't been modified in X amount of time.

Edit:

I feel like I am almost there. I'm trying something like this:

```
compile_service:
ifneq (echo $(($(date +%s)/60)), echo $(($(stat -c %Y $(FILES)/$(CLASS).class)/60)))
    CLASSPATH=$(RT) javac $(FILES)/$(CLASS).java
    $(CMD) $(FILES)/$(CLASS).class
else
    $(info Makefile: Recent file exists, using that instead)
endif
```

But this always fails (the message is printed).
Any clue what I'm doing wrong? Executing those commands in the terminal prints a good time that is accurate to the minute.

Comment: Your `ifneq` statements cannot work... you seem to be thinking you can write shell scripts inside the arguments if `ifneq`: you can't.  `ifneq` is a makefile construct, not a shell script or recipe: you can only use _make_ commands there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve your problem from different approach. I think the test should be part of shell-command instead of part of `make`-specific commands. For example:

```
compile_service:
  find YOURFILE -type f -Btime +5m -maxdepth 0 2>/dev/null && YOUR_DESIRED_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could make a "5 minute file" and use it as a target for the
file, but this solution seems simpler:

```
FILE        = myfile
NOW         = $$( date +%s )
FILE_MTIME  = $$( date -r $(FILE) +%s 2>/dev/null || echo 0 )
# FILE_AGE    = $$( echo $$(( ($(NOW) - $(FILE_MTIME))/60 )) )# # age in minutes
FILE_AGE    = $$(( ($(NOW) - $(FILE_MTIME))/60 ))#      # age in minutes
THRESHOLD   = 5#                                        # cutoff age in minutes
all:
        @echo -n "| $(FILE) "
        @test -f $(FILE) && echo "is $(FILE_AGE)m old" || echo "NOT FOUND"

        @test $(FILE_AGE) -ge $(THRESHOLD) && echo do nothing || make X

X:
        @echo .. do X recipe ...
```

Testing:

```
$ make all
| myfile NOT FOUND
do nothing
$ touch --date='4 min ago 55 sec ago' myfile
$ make all
| myfile is 4m old
.. do X recipe ...
$ make all
| myfile is 5m old
do nothing
```